# Symfony Forms - Creating a weight input type

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm moving an application to Symfony which records weights

There are 2 fields in the database, `weight` which is a decimal and `drams` which is an int
So a weight of 2 pounds 12 ounce 12 drams would be stored as `2.12` in the weight column and `12` in the drams column

I've created a custom form type for the weight to output the pounds and ounces as separate fields which works well

The problem I have is I'd like to also include the drams as part of the custom form type but without grouping it with the other two fields

E.g. my code in `buildForm`

```
->add('lb', IntegerType::class)
->add('oz', IntegerType::class, [
    'attr' => ['min' => 0, 'max' => 15],
])
->add('drams', IntegerType::class, [
    'attr' => ['min' => 0, 'max' => 15],
    'label' => 'Dr',
])
```

Generates 3 fields as expected but the names are `capture[weight][lb]`, `capture[weight][oz]` and `capture[weight][drams]`

I need the third to just be `capture[drams]`

I currently have this as a completely separate field

```
->add('weight', WeightInputType::class)
->add('drams')
```

But I need the output to have them all in the same wrapper for styling purposes so they look like this

[image: weight input]

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions of how to solve this?

Comment: How do you render this form? This could be done inside your template.

Comment: @fbuchlak it's a `FormType` class rendered using `form_widget`

Comment: you need to specify all the options of the dram field in your second part of code (you can remove it from the "weightType" (i'm not sure if it's clear enough)